# Ruby on rails - Devise - Show user created content only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am creating a basic ruby on rails application similar to zapier or ifttt. Users create recipes. I'd like to ONLY display recipes created by the user.

I've used device gem for authentication.

My questions:

Do i add "if user_signed_in?" on the top of each page? Can I add above yield on application layouts? Is there a better way?

Do i nest recipes within users?

Comment: Show some code which you've tried with so far.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an has many association between User and Recipe

You can do something like this. Use the current_user helper provided by devise and reference your recipes using current_user.

Therefore on any page concerning recipes you are only querying for the recipes the user created.

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_recipe, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /recipes
  # GET /recipes.json
  def index
    @recipes = current_user.recipes
  end

  # GET /recipes/1
  # GET /recipes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /recipes/new
  def new
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.build
  end

  # GET /recipes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /recipes
  # POST /recipes.json
  def create
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.build(recipe_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.save
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipie was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /recipes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /recipes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipie was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /recipes/1
  # DELETE /recipes/1.json
  def destroy
    @recipe.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to recipes_url, notice: 'Recipie was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_recipe
      @recipe = current_user.recipes.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def recipe_params
      params.fetch(:recipe, {...})
    end
end
```